# Parse error: syntax error in my PHP code with for loop

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, php

What's wrong in this piece of code? I try to use `strstr` in an array but I get an error message:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$array = array("modellini", "modelle");
for (i=0;$i<count($array;$i++)) 
{
    $key = strstr($url,$array[$i]);
    $keycap = ucwords($key);
    $bodytag = str_replace("-", " ", $keycap);

    if (false !== $key)
    {
?>

Prova<?php echo $bodytag ?>

<?php
    } else {
        echo 'No cars.';
    }
}
?>
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';'

... on this line:

```
for (i=0;$i<count($array;$i++))
```

Comment: Seems to be an typo as Danil says below. Next time add the error message to your question or an explanation of what is/went wrong.

Comment: Please try to make an effort and explain yourself what exactly you think it's wrong. If you force others to guess all the details you'll get less answers and less quality ones. I've completed the question for you.

Comment: And why break out of PHP at the `Prova<?php` line? Why not use `echo 'Prova' . $bodytag;` instead?

Comment: might be helpful as well: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14504459/367456)

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i=0;$i<count($array;$i++)){
```

reoplace by

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops..

The `for (i=0;$i<count($array;$i++)){`

should be:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
```